# PySpark window functions - fill data with prev non-zero values

Tags: python, pyspark, window

I have this dataframe:

```
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
|      Date|Count  |  GR|Count_NEW  |
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
|2012-01-02|     25| 100|         25|
|2012-01-02|    250| 110|        250|
|2012-01-03|     26| 100|         26|
|2012-01-03|    251| 110|        251|
|2012-01-04|     24| 100|         24|
|2012-01-04|    242| 110|        242|
|2012-01-05|     26| 100|         26|
|2012-01-05|    254| 110|        254|
|2012-01-06|      0| 100|          0|
|2012-01-06|    254| 110|        254|
|2012-01-07|     25| 100|         25|
|2012-01-07|    256| 110|        256|
|2012-01-08|     28| 100|         28|
|2012-01-08|      0| 110|          0|
|2012-01-09|     22| 100|         22|
|2012-01-09|    289| 110|        289|
|2012-01-10|     29| 100|         29|
|2012-01-10|    276| 110|        276|
|2012-01-11|     21| 100|         21|
|2012-01-11|    259| 110|        259|
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
```

You can use this to create the DF:

```
l = [
     ('100', '2012-01-02', 25),
     ('110', '2012-01-02', 250),
     ('100', '2012-01-03', 26),
     ('110', '2012-01-03', 251),
     ('100', '2012-01-04', 24),
     ('110', '2012-01-04', 242),
     ('100', '2012-01-05', 26),
     ('110', '2012-01-05', 254),
     ('100', '2012-01-06', 0),
     ('110', '2012-01-06', 254),
     ('100', '2012-01-07', 25),
     ('110', '2012-01-07', 256),
     ('100', '2012-01-08', 28),
     ('110', '2012-01-08', 0),
     ('100', '2012-01-09', 22),
     ('110', '2012-01-09', 289),
     ('100', '2012-01-10', 29),
     ('110', '2012-01-10', 276),
     ('100', '2012-01-11', 21),
     ('110', '2012-01-11', 259),
     ('100', '2012-01-12', 32),
     ('110', '2012-01-12', 280),
     ('100', '2012-01-13', 39),
     ('110', '2012-01-13', 290)
    ]

rdd = sparkc.parallelize(l)
member = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(GR=x[0], Date=x[1], Count=int(x[2])))

pdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(member)
```

Count and Count_NEW are same column (so ignore the Count_NEW).

I would like to fill up 2012-01-06 for GR=100 as 26
 I would like to fill up 2012-01-08 for GR=110 as 256

So it would look like this...

```
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
|      Date|Count  |  GR|Count_NEW  |
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
|2012-01-02|     25| 100|         25|
|2012-01-02|    250| 110|        250|
|2012-01-03|     26| 100|         26|
|2012-01-03|    251| 110|        251|
|2012-01-04|     24| 100|         24|
|2012-01-04|    242| 110|        242|
|2012-01-05|     26| 100|         26|
|2012-01-05|    254| 110|        254|
|2012-01-06|     26| 100|          0|
|2012-01-06|    254| 110|        254|
|2012-01-07|     25| 100|         25|
|2012-01-07|    256| 110|        256|
|2012-01-08|     28| 100|         28|
|2012-01-08|    256| 110|          0|
|2012-01-09|     22| 100|         22|
|2012-01-09|    289| 110|        289|
|2012-01-10|     29| 100|         29|
|2012-01-10|    276| 110|        276|
|2012-01-11|     21| 100|         21|
|2012-01-11|    259| 110|        259|
+----------+-------+----+-----------+
```

This means I would like to fill with previous NON-ZERO Values... How with window function I can do this??

I tried this but it does not work...

```
win = Window.partitionBy("GR").orderBy("Date")\
                .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df1 = df1.withColumn("Count", last('Count', True).over(win))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

After @corgiman's answer (Thanks a lot for your time and help)...

If the dataframe is like this... then @corgiman's soln does not work

```
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|Count|      Date| GR|Count_NEW|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|   25|2012-01-02|100|       25|
|  250|2012-01-02|110|      250|
|   26|2012-01-03|100|       26|
|  251|2012-01-03|110|      251|
|   24|2012-01-04|100|       24|
|  242|2012-01-04|110|      242|
|   26|2012-01-05|100|       26|
|  254|2012-01-05|110|      254|
|    0|2012-01-06|100|        0|
|  254|2012-01-06|110|      254|
|    0|2012-01-07|100|        0|
|  256|2012-01-07|110|      256|
|   28|2012-01-08|100|       28|
|    0|2012-01-08|110|        0|
|   22|2012-01-09|100|       22|
|  289|2012-01-09|110|      289|
|   29|2012-01-10|100|       29|
|  276|2012-01-10|110|      276|
|   21|2012-01-11|100|       21|
|  259|2012-01-11|110|      259|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
```

Here GR = 100 has 0 on 2012-01-07 and 2012-01-06 and I would like both to be filled with the previous non-zero value which is 26 on 2012-01-05.

So the required soln would be this...

```
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|Count|      Date| GR|Count_NEW|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|  250|2012-01-02|110|      250|
|  251|2012-01-03|110|      251|
|  242|2012-01-04|110|      242|
|  254|2012-01-05|110|      254|
|  254|2012-01-06|110|      254|
|  256|2012-01-07|110|      256|
|    0|2012-01-08|110|      256|
|  289|2012-01-09|110|      289|
|  276|2012-01-10|110|      276|
|  259|2012-01-11|110|      259|
|  280|2012-01-12|110|      280|
|  290|2012-01-13|110|      290|
|   25|2012-01-02|100|       25|
|   26|2012-01-03|100|       26|
|   24|2012-01-04|100|       24|
|   26|2012-01-05|100|       26|
|    0|2012-01-06|100|       26|
**|    0|2012-01-07|100|       26|**
|   28|2012-01-08|100|       28|
|   22|2012-01-09|100|       22|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
```

But it comes as...

```
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|Count|      Date| GR|Count_NEW|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|  250|2012-01-02|110|      250|
|  251|2012-01-03|110|      251|
|  242|2012-01-04|110|      242|
|  254|2012-01-05|110|      254|
|  254|2012-01-06|110|      254|
|  256|2012-01-07|110|      256|
|    0|2012-01-08|110|      256|
|  289|2012-01-09|110|      289|
|  276|2012-01-10|110|      276|
|  259|2012-01-11|110|      259|
|  280|2012-01-12|110|      280|
|  290|2012-01-13|110|      290|
|   25|2012-01-02|100|       25|
|   26|2012-01-03|100|       26|
|   24|2012-01-04|100|       24|
|   26|2012-01-05|100|       26|
|    0|2012-01-06|100|       26|
*|    0|2012-01-07|100|        0|*
|   28|2012-01-08|100|       28|
|   22|2012-01-09|100|       22|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
```

Comment: Main thing I am stuck here is how to include the ==0 condition inside the last function over the window. Basically how to include any set of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can change `0` values to `null` and use `ignorenulls` argument in the `last` method.

Example Code:

```
pdf = pdf.withColumn('Count', F.when(pdf['Count'] == 0, F.lit(None)).otherwise(pdf['Count']))

win = Window.partitionBy("GR").orderBy("Date")
s = F.last('Count', ignorenulls = True).over(win)


pdf = pdf.withColumn("Count", F.when(pdf['Count'] == F.lag('Count').over(win), s).otherwise(s)

pdf.show()
```

The output will be:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| GR|      Date|Count|
+---+----------+-----+
|110|2012-01-02|  250|
|110|2012-01-03|  251|
|110|2012-01-04|  242|
|110|2012-01-05|  254|
|110|2012-01-06|  254|
|110|2012-01-07|  256|
|110|2012-01-08|  256|
|110|2012-01-09|  289|
|110|2012-01-10|  276|
|110|2012-01-11|  259|
|110|2012-01-12|  280|
|110|2012-01-13|  290|
|100|2012-01-02|   25|
|100|2012-01-03|   26|
|100|2012-01-04|   24|
|100|2012-01-05|   26|
|100|2012-01-06|   26|
|100|2012-01-07|   25|
|100|2012-01-08|   28|
|100|2012-01-09|   22|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to get what you want by using `when` and `otherwise`.

You just need to change your code from:

```
win = Window.partitionBy("GR").orderBy("Date")\
                .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df1 = df1.withColumn("Count", last('Count', True).over(win))
```

to:

```
win = Window.partitionBy("GR").orderBy("Date")\
                .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df1 = df1.withColumn("Count_new", F.when(df1.Count==0, F.last('Count', True).over(win)).otherwise(pdf.Count))
```

The output will be:

```
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|Count|      Date| GR|Count_new|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
|  250|2012-01-02|110|      250|
|  251|2012-01-03|110|      251|
|  242|2012-01-04|110|      242|
|  254|2012-01-05|110|      254|
|  254|2012-01-06|110|      254|
|  256|2012-01-07|110|      256|
|    0|2012-01-08|110|      256|
|  289|2012-01-09|110|      289|
|  276|2012-01-10|110|      276|
|  259|2012-01-11|110|      259|
|  280|2012-01-12|110|      280|
|  290|2012-01-13|110|      290|
|   25|2012-01-02|100|       25|
|   26|2012-01-03|100|       26|
|   24|2012-01-04|100|       24|
|   26|2012-01-05|100|       26|
|    0|2012-01-06|100|       26|
|   25|2012-01-07|100|       25|
|   28|2012-01-08|100|       28|
|   22|2012-01-09|100|       22|
+-----+----------+---+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @corgiman. However it does not work if there are multiple 0's in consecutively, then it does not work... I will try to edit the main question as I cannot add that long a message as a comment here due to word count limitations

Comment: @SanDNath Solat's solution should work for you in that case. I was going to suggest the same thing as him as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both of you. I tried this in the meantime and it worked (it is similar to Solat's thinking - converting 0's to nulls). This is what I did and it worked great!

```
df1 = pdf.withColumn("Count_NEW", \
                    when(~isnan("Count") & col("Count").isNotNull()\
                        & (col("Count") > 0), col("Count"))\
                               .otherwise(None) )
win = Window.partitionBy("GR").orderBy("Date")\
                .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Count_NEW", last('Count_NEW', True).over(win))
```